# Open URLs from my email newsletter in Mobile App

Tags: marketing-cloud, deep-linking

We send daily newsletter with our new products. We also have an Android/iOS app.

For now, I saw that if we open a link from an email with our mobile (from Gmail app for instance), the link is opened on the website (web mobile version).
But if I deactivate the Click tracking, the link is opened on the app, on the product page.

So I understand that our App is not able to open Marketing cloud "encoded" URLs.
My dev told me that he can make the app able to recognize all encoded URL (as they are al starting with http://click.myOwnPrivateDomain.com/?qs=...)  however, he won't be able to redirect the user to the good page (our product page). He can only send them to our App homepage.

So I understand we have to choose between "deeplinks" and "click tracking" in our emails.

Can you please tell me what you think about that ?

Thanks in advance !

Kind regards,

David

Comment: @NoorAlam are you sure this is the correct link?

Comment: Hi there ! Thank you for your feedback. Yes, I'm not sure that would help me to change a parameter in Service Cloud ? I'm not the admin of Service Cloud, I guess I can manage this on my end ? 
I hope you can give me more details !

Comment: Sorry that was the wrong link. The marketing cloud deep linking solution is this https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_implement_ios_universal_link.htm&type=5 though this is for ios

Comment: Hi @NoorAlam, thank you for this link ! We saw this link but we are not sure for the very 2 first points. Should we buy a SAP only for the deeplinks on iOS ? 
We already have a SAP in place for the email (especially the private domain which is usefull for the branding). 
Also, for the SSL : we didn't add this for now as I'm not sure where and how we should do this. We'll do it soon for this point : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000355099&type=1&mode=1
Do you think it has something to do with the SSL mentionned in your URL ?
I appreciate your help ! Thanks !

Comment: I don't think you need a new SAP if you already have one, To add a SSL that's currently done through SFMC support.

Comment: OK ! That's sure I didn't ask for SSL to the support.
The link I give you about the mixed content seems to be ALSO fixed by the SSL. The documentation ( https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000339842&type=1&mode=1) says SSL will "secure view. and click" which is what is asked for the deeplinks, and "Securing portfolio content URLs" which is what is asked for the mixed contents. I'll have to see if I have to buy 1 or 2 times this SSL, I don't know for now.